# REGEXP_SUBSTR Is taking more time for execution in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, split, substr

I am trying to split a comma separated email string into individual email ids which are comma separated but each email id is enclosed inside single quotation.

**My Input is** `'one@gmail.com,two@gamil.com,three@gmail.com,four@gmail.com'`

**My Output Should be:** `'one@gmail.com','two@gamil.com','three@gmail.com','four@gmail.com'`

I am going to use the output string above in oracle query where condition like...

```
Where EmailId's in ( 'one@gmail.com','two@gamil.com','three@gmail.com','four@gmail.com');
```

I am using the following code to achieve this

```
 WHERE EMAIL IN 
                    (REGEXP_SUBSTR('one@gmail.com,two@gamil.com,three@gmail.com,four@gmail.com' ,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL))
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('one@gmail.com,two@gamil.com,three@gmail.com,four@gmail.com' ) - LENGTH(REPLACE('one@gmail.com,two@gamil.com,three@gmail.com,four@gmail.com' , ',', '')) +1;
```

But the above query taking 60 seconds to return only 16 records. Can any one suggest me the best approach for this...

Comment: I guess your query is slow because of hierarhical query (connect by) and not regex parsing. Can you re-write your query without using connect by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
WHERE email IN (
  select regexp_substr('one@gmail.com,two@gamil.com,three@gmail.com,four@gmail.com','[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
  connect by regexp_substr('one@gmail.com,two@gamil.com,three@gmail.com,four@gmail.com', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );
```